How do I ensure my train's length will be the same after replacing engines?
I have found a few times that when I replace the engine of a train, the resulting train is a little bit longer or shorter than the original.  Maybe a 7.0 train becomes 7.1 or 6.9.  Obviously this is a problem, but I can't find a good solution.  The engines don't say how long they are in the purchase window.  What I've been doing is buying new trains that are only engines in question, and then I compare them, but I can't do this for obsolete engines since you can't buy them anymore.  I know the sprites are to-scale, but it still isn't always easy to tell visually.
Any ideas?

Could you explain why this is a problem? It's been years since I last played openttd. I recall some engines are two wagons instead of one which is important but also very obvious. I don't recall ever noticing the difference you describe. Might be newer feature?

@quarague I am using some newgrf's that add more trains, not the trains from the base game.  Some are hard to tell apart.  A train that is 6.9 instead of 7 is missing out on some cargo capacity.  What's worse is when a train is 7.1 instead of 7.  Then they don't fit in 7-length stations and take ages to load/unload.  Whats more, on a busy line those extra 0.1's really add up.  Every 7 trains it's like an additional train is on the line in terms of congestion.

This can only really be fixed by changing the newGRF or using a newGRF that does not change train lengths.
But openTTD is highly customizeable! I recommend you pick a set of GRFs that align more with your preferences.
It would be useful to, when choosing a newGRF, check the priorities of the author(s). Most trainsets have extensive documentation that will tell you more about that quickly. Some prioritise 'realistic', meaning; they're a re-creation of whatever real-life trains are in the set, as accurate as openTTD lets them be (which is not-very due to the long-standing strangeness of diagonal movement in the Openttd metric space). Examples of sets that do this are 'Japanset' or 'NARS'. You can tell them apart by their names; if trainsets refer to real-life countries or companies you can tell it's (very likely) going to be this type of set. Quite often such newGRFs are annoying to use for gameplay, having a bunch of suboptimal trains in them (trains that have strictly worse stats than others, and aren't available earlier or cheaper for it), an overly large selection of carriages, difficult to tell the owner of trains apart in multiplayer/vs AI, low speed limits, low power/speed ratios, low TE, and also your problem; very slightly differing locomotive lengths.
Other authors prioritise gameplay over this realism though. You should try out those newGRFs instead. Examples include NUTS, Pineapple trains, Iron horse, and UKRS (from less to more gameplay/realism tradeoff). NUTS tries to:

Match train stats to curve lengths when using realistic accelleration. (So that it's easy to make trains that don't slow down in curves).
Make locomotives and cars universal length (so it's easy to upgrade trains).
Be compatible with a variety of industry newGRFs.
Have meaningful speed/power increases over time for its time period (1900-2070 intro dates). Realistic sets often have long periods where train stats don't meaningfully increase.
Provide a large selection of useful options (each 'line' of locos is best-in-class, there's no 'dead' options in the depot buy screen, which most realistic sets have).
Allow for large, very busy networks of any corner length and railtype (provided breakdowns are off and realistic accelleration is on). Realistic sets tend to have trains that are too low power compared to their speeds to allow for openttdcoop style BBHs, as it's not realistic to have a train go by every 3 seconds.

It does not try to;

Challenge the player financially (the NUTS trains are cheap to buy/run just like the defaults). Use a separate mod to multiply costs to do this.
Be realistic at all.

All of these things lead to faster gameplay, and allow you to build large complex networks much more comfortably.
